# How do I append/prepend/concatenate a string to all field names in a SELECT * statement in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to SELECT fields from a table as part of a bigger query and I would like all of the field names for a particular table to be prepended or appended with a string without having to manually rename each field individually.

Example:

```sql
WITH a AS (
  SELECT 'value_in_table_a' AS val1, 'another' AS val2
),
b AS (
    SELECT 'value_in_table_b' AS val
)
SELECT
  a.*,
  b.*
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
```

I would like the result to be something like:

| a_val1 | a_val2 | b_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_in_table_a | another | value_in_table_b |

But, I want to avoid having to manually rename each field -- which can be annoyingly tedious when I have 50 field names -- like:

```sql
SELECT
  a.val1 AS a_val1,
  a.val2 AS a_val2,
  b.val AS b_val
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
```

I know that I can do:

```sql
SELECT
  a,
  b
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
```

And then the result is a STRUCT type which prepends the field names with the table name, but is there something more general?

Something like:

```sql
SELECT
  a.* AS 'a_'*,
  b.* AS *'_b'
FROM a
CROSS JOIN b
```

To get:

| a_val1 | a_val2 | val_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_in_table_a | another | value_in_table_b |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below solution

```
create temp function extract_keys(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
  """;
create temp function flatten_json(input string) returns string language js as '''
  function flattenObj(obj, parent = '', res = {}){
    for(let key in obj){
        let propName = parent ? parent + '.' + key : key;
        if(typeof obj[key] == 'object'){
            flattenObj(obj[key], propName, res);
        } else {
            res[propName] = obj[key];
        }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(res);
  }
  return flattenObj(JSON.parse(input));
  ''';
create temp table temp_table as (
  select offset, key, value, format('%t', t) row_id
  from (select a, b from a cross join b) t, 
  unnest([struct(to_json_string(t) as json)]),
  unnest([struct(flatten_json(json) as leaves)]),
  unnest(extract_keys(leaves)) key with offset
  join unnest(extract_values(leaves)) value with offset
  using(offset) 
);  

execute immediate (
  select '''
    select * except(row_id) from (select * except(offset) from temp_table)
    pivot (any_value(value) for replace(key, '.', '_') in (''' || keys || "))"
  from (
    select string_agg('"' || replace(key, '.', '_') || '"', ',' order by offset) keys 
    from (select key, min(offset) as offset from temp_table group by key)
  )
);
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]